# AEM (CQ5.6.1) local maven deployment only works sometimes

Tags: aem

I've gotten some weird effects lately, where sometimes when I deploy my CQ application via Maven to my local AEM Server, it would't update correctly.

E.g. when changing something in a dialog of a component, I have to delete the /app/myapp folder in CRX and deploy again to get changes to appear.

I'm also having a hard time reproducing the effect. It happens seemingly in random intervals.

Comment: How are you uploading a package - which Maven plugin do you use?
How does your `filter.xml` file look like?
The case of dialog not refreshing is really weird. This should work with no issues with the browser refresh in mind.

Comment: Well, I'm just using the content-package maven plugin http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/core/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool/vlt-mavenplugin.html

I did not customize the filter.xml at all. 
The weird thing is - the maven plugin shows that the nodes needing update are updated. But it seemingly has no effect on the repository until I delete those nodes and redeploy.

Comment: could you please paste your filter.xml file?

Comment: Um.. it looks quite.. empty:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your `filter.xml` file. This descriptor should contain all the root paths for your application so most probably: `/app/myapp`, `/etc/designs/myapp` and maybe couple others.

For more information please check [vault documentation](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/core/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool/vlt-mavenplugin.html) (section using filters). This file is used by CQ package manager to install the content.

In previous CQ versions there was a behaviour that filters were almost ignored. Starting from CQ 5.6 if any content path does not match `filter.xml` regexps it won't be installed. This does not match exactly your issue but kindly check if updating `filter.xml` file helps.

Comment: Here's the one I use now:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/apps/myapp" />
    <filter root="/etc/designs/myapp" />
</workspaceFilter>

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use for our project and has worked flawlessly on AEM6 but should also work perfectly on CQ 5.6.  Replace "ourProject" with whatever is appropriate and let me know if you still have issues.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/apps/ourProject">
      <exclude pattern=".*install" />
    </filter>

    <filter root="/etc/ourProject"/>
    <filter root="/etc/designs/ourProject" />
    <filter root="/etc/widgets" />
    <filter root="/etc/workflows" mode="update"/>
</workspaceFilter>
```